# SubBuffer Implementation

Tags: c++

I have to work with the following files at the bottom.
The problem is BufferSptr which i have to use.
I can create a BufferSptr by doing the following.

```
BufferSptr buff (new Buffer (pMediaData->Size()) );
```

I can also access and pass it to the functions in a media player where it is being used.
What i want to do is pass a BufferSptr but access not all of it but
some partial content. I see the files below define some way to do it but it is not working for me

for eg i tried this, but does not work.

```
BufferSptr subbuffer (&buff,0,100);
```

So what i want is to use BufferSptr with partial content. thanks

The Buffer.h class is

```
namespace ahs {

/** A Buffer provides a partial view to a block of memory.  For any
 *  given Buffer, subbuffers can be created that provide a partial view
 *  of the original Buffer contents.  If all the Buffers to a block of
 *  memory are deleted, the block itself is freed automatically.
 */
class Buffer
{
/* Data types */
public:
typedef shared_ptr<Buffer> BufferSptr;
typedef shared_ptr<const Buffer> ConstBufferSptr;

/* Member functions */
public:
/** Create a new buffer of the given size (in Bytes) using the default
 *  backend */
Buffer( size_t size );

/** Create a new buffer using a provided backend store */
Buffer( const BufferBackendSptr& pBackend );

/** Create a subbuffer */
Buffer( Buffer* container, int offs, int sz );

/** Create a subbuffer (equivalent to the constructor based method) */
Buffer* CreateSubbuffer( int offs, int sz );
const Buffer* CreateConstSubbuffer( int offs, int sz ) const;

/** Get a pointer to the data */
void* GetData();
const void* GetData() const;

/** Returns the size of the buffer data */
size_t Size() const;

/* Member data */
protected:
/** Pointer to the Backend
 *
 *  We use this to keep a reference around, making sure the data does
 *  not get thrown away.  The other purpose is to create subbuffers.
 */
shared_ptr<BufferBackend> mpBackend;

/** Pointer to the data of this buffer
 *
 *  In the general case, pData points somewhere to the interior of the
 *  data block owned by pBackend.
 */
char*   mpData;

/** The buffer size */
size_t  muSize;

};

typedef Buffer::BufferSptr BufferSptr;
typedef Buffer::ConstBufferSptr ConstBufferSptr;

inline const void* Buffer::GetData() const
{
return mpData;
}

inline void* Buffer::GetData()
{
return mpData;
}

inline size_t Buffer::Size() const
{
return muSize;
}

} // end namespace ahs

#endif
```

Buffer.cpp is

```
using namespace ahs;

Buffer::Buffer(size_t sz) : mpBackend(new BufferBackend(sz)),
                        mpData(mpBackend->mpBlock),
                        muSize(sz)
{
}

Buffer::Buffer( const BufferBackendSptr& pBackend )
: mpBackend( pBackend )
, mpData( mpBackend->mpBlock )
, muSize( mpBackend->muSize )
{
}

Buffer::Buffer(Buffer *container, int offs, int sz)
{
assert(offs + sz <= container->muSize);

#if 0 // TODO: Premature optimization, either enable or take out.
if(sz == 0)
{
    /* Special case: Try to avoid holding an unnecessary reference
       to the backend. */
    muSize = 0;
    mpBackend = (BufferBackend *)0;
    mpData = 0;
}
else
#endif
{
    mpBackend = container->mpBackend;
    muSize = sz;
    mpData = &mpData[offs];
}
}

Buffer* Buffer::CreateSubbuffer(int offs, int sz)
{
return new Buffer(this, offs, sz);
}

const Buffer* Buffer::CreateConstSubbuffer(int offs, int sz) const
{
return const_cast<Buffer *>(this)->CreateSubbuffer(offs, sz);
}
```

Bufferbackend.h is

Class that owns a block of data which can be accessed by different
 *  Buffers.  The point of having a BufferBackend is so that each Buffer
 *  can contain a shared pointer referring to the same data block held
 *  by a BufferBackend.  This Backend will then automatically go away
 *  once all references to it disappear.
 *
 *  Subclasses of this class should be created that use specific
 *  memory allocation/deallocation functions.
 */
    class BufferBackend
    {

    /* Friends */
    public:
    friend class Buffer;

```
/* Data types */
public:
typedef shared_ptr<BufferBackend> BufferBackendSptr;

/* Member functions */
public:
BufferBackend( size_t sz );

virtual ~BufferBackend();
```

// BufferBackend( );

```
protected:
/** Virtual function to allocate memory */
 void Allocate();

/** Virtual function to deallocate memory */
 void Deallocate();

private:
/* Disallow copying or assignment */
BufferBackend(const BufferBackend&);
BufferBackend operator=(const BufferBackend&);

/* Member data */
protected:
char*   mpBlock;
size_t  muSize;

};

typedef BufferBackend::BufferBackendSptr BufferBackendSptr;

inline BufferBackend::BufferBackend( size_t sz )
: muSize( sz )
{
Allocate();
}

inline BufferBackend::~BufferBackend()
{
Deallocate();
}

} // end namespace ahs

#endif /* BUFFER_BACKEND_H */
```

Bufferbackend.cpp

## include "BufferBackend.h"

```
using namespace ahs;

void BufferBackend::Allocate()
{
mpBlock = new char[ muSize ];
}

void BufferBackend::Deallocate()
{
delete[] mpBlock;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

BufferSptr is just the shared pointer: you have to assign a buffer to it (you have to create the buffer).
If buff is another BufferSptr (another shared pointer), then I would try:

```
BufferSptr subbuffer (buff->CreateSubbuffer(0,100));
```

or

```
BufferSptr subbuffer (new Buffer(buff.get(), 0,100));
```

Comment: the subbuffer returns the buffersptr but i do not get any data from it... if i pass it to my player it behaves like there is nothing to decode, also i printed the contents of the buffer, it is empty.... any suggestions... even memcpy cannot write to it...

Comment: This is because the implementation of the constructor Buffer::Buffer(Buffer *container, int offs, int sz) is probably aking data from the wrong place. Shouldn't mpData = &mpData[offs]; be mpData = &(container->mpData[offs]); ??

Comment: it does not solve the problem, i have edited the post and put the **bufferbackend** file too...please take a look.. thanks

Comment: @fammi The problem is that the constructor `Buffer::Buffer(Buffer *container, int offs, int sz)` leaves mpData uninitialized.
When the constructor is called, mpData is uninitialized, and then later mpData(uninitialized)+off is assigned again to mpData, leaving it pointing at a random memory location (therefore a crash should happen when you try to read or write into the subbuffer).

I would replace the line `mpData = &mpData[offs];` with `mpData = container->mpData + offs;`

It should work like this.